# cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file

Tags: java, android, gradle

After i update my android studio and gradle i have problem with my gradle

Here is my gradle implements

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation project(path: ':domain')
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.therealshabi:AutoImageFlipper:v1.4.1'
implementation "com.github.firdausmaulan:GlideSlider:1.3.1"

implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'


implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
implementation 'com.github.santalu:diagonal-imageview:1.0.3'

implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialleanback:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.ome450901:SimpleRatingBar:1.4.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'

implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.6'

implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation ('com.github.hamsaadev:RTLMaterialSpinner:V1.0.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}

implementation 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.4'
implementation 'com.wajahatkarim3.EasyFlipView:EasyFlipView:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'
implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'


implementation project(path: ':ui')
```

it is ok when build gradle, but when i want running the project show this error

```
error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found
```

i see other answer about same question but they dont work for me

Comment: what is your compileSdkVersion? please upload the entire gradle file you have.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

Comment: i solved this problem by update

compileSdkVersion 26

targetSdkVersion 27